# How Liquibase is currently handling character encoding?

Tags: sql, encoding, liquibase, changeset

Could you explain how Liquibase (eg. version 3.3.2) is currently handling character encoding ?

1/ Changesets in XML format are declared in UTF-8. However, some changes can be directly declared inline within XML (eg. 'sql') and others can be imported directly from external files (eg. 'sqlFile').

For the first ones (inline), could you confirm that these changes must be then obviously in the same character encoding than the XML changeset (so only UTF-8)?
Is it possible to have changes in different character encoding than UTF-8 ?
If so, is it then mandatory to set a specific encoding within the XML declaration (eg. encoding="ISO-8859-1") instead of UTF-8 ?
And finally, how could we inform Liquibase that these changesets should be parsed with that specific encoding (eg. Java system property) ?

For the second ones (imported as file), could you confirm that these changes could be set in another character encoding than UTF-8 ?
If so, could you confirm that we must set the "encoding" attribute of these changes to the appropriate character encoding ?
Is it then true that we could have an XML changeset declared as UTF-8 but changes set in a different character encoding (eg. encoding="ISO-8859-1") ?
And finally, do we need to inform Liquibase in any way to parse the changeset in a specific encoding (eg. Java system property) ?

2/ Changesets in SQL format are also a different story. It is not possible to set any metadata within these files to inform Liquibase about which character encoding to use when parsing these files.

What character encoding Liquibase is using to parse these files ? UTF-8 or any another character encoding ?
Is it possible to have changes in different character encoding than UTF-8 ?
If so, how to declare it and how could we inform Liquibase about the character encoding to use to parse these files (eg. Java system property) ?

As far as I know, several Java system properties can be set with Liquibase:

- file.encoding,
- liquibase.file.encoding,
- liquibase.ouputFileEncoding.

However these Java system properties seems more to influence the writing process of the changes than the parsing process.

Currently, most of our databases are using ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 but Liquibase seems to handle correctly UTF-8 changesets only. Your answers to these questions will help us a lot to understand

- what features related to character encoding are provided by
  Liquibase, and
- what restrictions exist depending on the used
  changeset format.

I thank you in advance for your help,

Bertrand

Answer (score 3):

I think files are read in liquibase with the [FileSystemResourceAccessor](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/FileSystemResourceAccessor.java) and there is no encoding which you can specifically set. 
Which means it will use what ever the underlying Java will use. And InputStreamReader will use the default system encoding.

So you should be able to influence this by setting the the encoding for the JVM with:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

XML files are parsed with SAX parser (and maybe the SAX parser will do further stuff to recognize the encoding.)

For changesets in sql file format it will use the [UtfBomAwareReader](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/UtfBomAwareReader.java) reader. 
Though there is code to try to identify the encoding in [UtfBomAwareReader](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/UtfBomAwareReader.java) I think the [SqlChangeLogParser](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/sql/SqlChangeLogParser.java) is not using it (as of right now) and instead just defaults to "UTF-8".

This is to the best of my knowledge. So before you make big design decision based on this try to validate it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... I look at Liquibase code and found several issues. All parsers are using [UtfBomAwareReader](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/UtfBomAwareReader.java). But any of them set the charset name to use when creating an instance of this class. So all change log files are read (whatever change log file format is used) using UTF-8 as the default charset name. As a result, formatted sql change log files are always parse as UTF-8 even if these changes are targeted to another charset.

Comment: [UtfBomAwareReader](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/UtfBomAwareReader.java) instances are created directly or through the method getStreamContents() of the class [StreamUtil](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/StreamUtil.java). A charset name can be specified in both cases but in each change log parser, no charset name is provided or the charset name is set to null. So UTF-8 is used by defauft.

Comment: [SqlChangeLogParser](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/sql/SqlChangeLogParser.java) uses [StreamUtil](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/StreamUtil.java) but set the charset name to null. So UTF-8 is always used.

Comment: [FormattedSqlChangelogParser](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java) creates directely an instance of [UtfBomAwareReader](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/UtfBomAwareReader.java) but without setting a default charset name. So UTF-8 is always used.

Comment: [XMLChangeLogSAXParser](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/xml/XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java) creates directly an instance of [UtfBomStripperInputStream](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/UtfBomStripperInputStream.java). As no encoding is set explicitly on the [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html), the SAX parser will then use the auto-detecting feature of SAX using an algorithm such as the one in the XML specification.

Comment: Regarding XML change logs imported as external files, it is possible to specify through the 'encoding'  attribute of the change in which encoding the stream should be read.

Comment: [SQLFileChange](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/core/SQLFileChange.java) uses [StreamUtil](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/StreamUtil.java) and the encoding set through the 'encoding' attribute of the change. If no encoding is set, UTF-8 is then always used.

Comment: I don't know if you should use the comment section here to write down all of your findings on how liquibase works / not works. Consider to edit my answer if you find important details. And consider to open an enhancement request in liquibase jira for this.

Comment: I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2289 as a starting point to better handle non-utf8 issues as I am working on Liquibase 4.0. Please add requirements and examples to that

Comment: Thanks Nathan for creating this JIRA. Meanwhile we managed to solve this issue converting all our sql change sets in UTF-8. As our databases are not always in UTF-8, we need then to add an extra step after exporting database objects as ddl files.

Answer (score 1):

set it before executing liquibase, e.g. in a Windows environment:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
liquibase.bat
```